# Magento Custom module phtml file call selected page only in system configuration

Tags: magento2, module

I am using Magento 2 I want to display phtml some page only that i need to select backend. How to display selected page only?

```
class Selectpage implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface{

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $options;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * To option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        if (!$this->options) {
            $this->options = $this->collectionFactory->create()->toOptionIdArray();
        }
        $extra_pages_list = array(
            array(
                'value' => 'catalog_category_view',
                'label' => 'Category Page',
            ),
            array(
                'value' => 'catalog_product_view',
                'label' => 'Product Page',
            ),
            array(
                'value' => 'checkout_cart_index',
                'label' => 'Shoopping Cart',
            ),
            array(
                'value' => 'checkout_index_index',
                'label' => 'Checkout',
            )
            );
        $allPages = array_merge($this->options,$extra_pages_list);
        return $allPages;
    }
```

**my.phtml**

```
 <?php 
$field = $this->getConfigValue('popup/general/page');
    $pages = explode(',',$field);
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context')->getRequest();
//echo $request->getFullActionName();exit;
$t1 = "default"; /* don't change this */
if ($request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
  $t1 = $request->getFullActionName();
}
elseif($request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view'){
  $t1 = $request->getFullActionName();
}
elseif($request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_index'){
  $t1 = $request->getFullActionName();
}
elseif($request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_index_index'){
  $t1 = $request->getFullActionName();
}
elseif($this->getPageDetails()){
  $t1 = $this->getPageDetails();
}

?>


<?php 
  //$oN = '';
  //if(in_array($t1,$this->getOverlayPages())){
    //$oN = "one";
   // echo "ok";
    //echo $t1;
    //var_dump($this->getOverlayPages());
  /*}
  elseif($t1 && in_array($t1,$this->getOverlayPages('two'))){
    $oN = "two";
  }
  elseif($t1 && in_array($t1,$this->getOverlayPages('three'))){
    $oN = "three";
  }*/
?>


<?php if(in_array($t1,$this->getOverlayPages())):?>
<div style="display:none;" id="OverlayContent">
   <div class="overlay-contents">
      <h2 class="overlay-title"><?php echo $this->getTitle(); ?></h2>
      <?php echo $this->getStaticblockcontent();?>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {      
      jQuery(document).bind("mouseleave", function(e){
        if (e.pageY - jQuery(window).scrollTop() <= 1){  
        if(!readCookie('<?php echo $this->getCookieName();?>')){ //check cookie             
            if(!jQuery('.fancybox-wrap').length){                   
                jQuery.fancybox({
                    'width': '<?php echo $this->getWidth();?>',
                    'height': '<?php echo $this->getHeight();?>',
                    'transitionIn': 'fade',
                    'transitionOut': 'fade',
                    'showCloseButton': true,    
                    'fitToView'   : false,
                    'autoSize'    : false,
                    'fixed': false,
                    'href': "#OverlayContent",
                    'autoCenter': false,
                    'helpers'     : { 
                           'overlay' : {'closeClick': false}
                           }, 
                    'afterClose' : function(){
                        <?php if($this->getCookieExpireTime()){ ?>
                            createCookie('<?php echo $this->getCookieName();?>', 1, '<?php echo $this->getCookieExpireTime();?>');
                        <?php } ?>
                    }                        
                }); 
                }//cookie check                 
            }
        }   
     });  
        <?php if(!$this->getCookieExpireTime()){ ?>
            eraseCookie('<?php echo $this->getCookieName();?>');
        <?php } ?>
    });  



/**To create cookie**/
function createCookie(name, value, time) {
var time = parseInt(time);
    if (time) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (time * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}
/**To read cookie**/
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = escape(name) + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return unescape(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
    }
    return null;
}
/**To erase cookie**/
function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}


</script>

<?php endif;?>
```

How to display ** Content ** in selected page's only ?

[image]

Comment: It's working for all page except cms page how to achive this

Answer (score 3):

you can set condition in your block,
Here my block php file contains :

```
protected $_request;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_request = $request;
    ...
}


public function isHomepage()
{

    if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And call that function in your .phtml file
like this :

```
$isHome = $block->isHomepage();
if ($isHome)
{
       your page code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For get page action you need to used something like this :

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    ...
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

Then you can get the action name :

```
$action = $this->request->getFullActionName();
```

In your spacific case, you need to replace this line :

```
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context')->getRequest();
```

into this

```
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http')->getRouteName();
```

Comment: can you please tell me where i need to add

Comment: I updated answer, please check.

Comment: @Kothari IF above code help you, then mark as solution so other get help.

Comment: How to check in if condition

Comment: I want to show below div only selected page in backend

Comment: You can used above code in your phtml file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47446/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-kothari).

Comment: can you please tell me that condition

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way in case you're dealing with a core block and don't want to rewrite it would be to use an event on the `controller_action_predispatch` event to set the `t1` variable dynamically:

in `etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="custom_module_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\MyObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then in `Observer/MyObserver.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
    protected $_layout;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
    ) {
        $this->_layout = $layout;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
        $block = $this->_layout->getBlock('name_of_your_block');
        if ($block) {
            switch($action) {
                case "catalog_category_view":
                case "catalog_product_view":
                case "checkout_cart_index":
                case "checkout_index_index":
                    $block->setMyVariable($action);
                    break;
                default:
                    $block->setMyVariable("default");
                    break;
            }
            if ($pageDetails = $block->getPageDetails()) {
                 $block->setMyVariable($pageDetails);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NB: don't forget to replace `name_of_your_block` with the name of your block in the layout.

Also double check that bit, as I don't know what `getPageDetails` does:

```
if ($pageDetails = $block->getPageDetails()) {
     $block->setMyVariable($pageDetails);
}
```

Finally, in your template you can replace:

```
$t1 = "default"; /* don't change this */
if ($request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
  $t1 = $request->getFullActionName();
}
elseif($request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view'){
  $t1 = $request->getFullActionName();
}
elseif($request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_index'){
  $t1 = $request->getFullActionName();
}
elseif($request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_index_index'){
  $t1 = $request->getFullActionName();
}
elseif($this->getPageDetails()){
  $t1 = $this->getPageDetails();
}
```

With:

```
$t1 = $block->getMyVariable();
```

Comment: What i need to add here (name_of_your_block ) it will work for my problem

Comment: @Kothari you need to replace `name_of_your_block` with the name you defined for your block in your layout