# Magento 2 how to get all cms pages in system configuration

Tags: magento2, configuration, cms, source-model

**System Configuration**

```
<field id="test" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="11" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
 <label>Cms Page</label>
<source_model>Namespace\Module\Model\Test</source_model>
</field>
```

**Test.php**

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [
            [
                'label' => __('-- Please select --'),
                'value' => '',
            ],
            [
                'label' => __('Home Page '),
                'value' => 'cms_index_index',
            ],
            [
                'label' => __('404 Page'),
                'value' => 'cms_page_view',
            ],
            [
                'label' => __('Product'),
                'value' => 'catalog_product_view',
            ],
            [
                'label' => __('Category'),
                'value' => 'catalog_category_view',
            ],

        ];
        return $options;
```

**How to get all pages dynamically ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `Magento\Cms\Model\Config\Source\Page` source model.

So replace:

```
<source_model>Namespace\Module\Model\Test</source_model>
```

With:

```
<source_model>Magento\Cms\Model\Config\Source\Page</source_model>
```

Comment: I want to add some custom page select option also category,product,cart etc...

Comment: @Kothari that is not a list of CMS pages then you'll have to create your own source model

Comment: can you please help me this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142174/magento-custom-module-phtml-file-call-selected-page-only-in-system-configuration

Answer (score 2):

You can use CMS config model into your system.xml to get pages dynamically.

```
<field id="test" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="11" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
   <label>Cms Page</label>
   <source_model>Magento\Cms\Model\Config\Source\Page</source_model>
</field>
```

For reference you can find the below file.

```
\vendor\magento\module-cms\etc\adminhtml\system.xml
```

Comment: I want to add some custom page select option also category,product,cart etc...

Answer (score 0):

I have used the search criteria filter and filtered based on store views. Please check.

```
    <?php
namespace Custom\Links\Helper;

use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Store\Api\StoreWebsiteRelationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $pageRepositoryInterface;
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    protected $storeManager;  
    protected $logger;
    protected $request; 
    protected $sortOrderFactory;  

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
        PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepositoryInterface,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        RequestInterface $request,
        StoreWebsiteRelationInterface $storeWebsiteRelation,
        SortOrderFactory $sortOrderFactory      
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->sortOrderFactory = $sortOrderFactory;
        $this->pageRepositoryInterface = $pageRepositoryInterface;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->storeWebsiteRelation = $storeWebsiteRelation;
    }
    /**
     * Filter pages based on the store views for system configuration fi
     * @return PageInterface[] 
     * @throws InputException 
     * @throws LocalizedException 
     */
    public function getPages() 
    {

        $storeId = $this->getWebsiteId();
        $sortBasedOnPageTitle = $this->sortOrderFactory->create()
            ->setField('title')
            ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter('store_id', $storeId, 'in')
            ->setSortOrders([$sortBasedOnPageTitle])
            ->create();
        $pages = $this->pageRepositoryInterface->getList(
            $searchCriteria
        )->getItems();
        return $pages;

    }

    public function getWebsiteId()
    {
        $storeId = (int) $this->request->getParam('store', 0);
        if ($storeId > 0) {
            return [0,$storeId];
        }
        $websiteId = (int) $this->request->getParam('website', 0);
        $storeId = $this->storeWebsiteRelation->getStoreByWebsiteId($websiteId);
        return [0,$storeId];
    }
}
```