# Magento 2 cms page cms page Identifier

Tags: magento2, cms

How to get cms page FullActionName()

```
$request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index'
```

**Now,i want to get cms pages identifier name at that cms page**

In Magento 1, I used this `Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier()` it will get all so that i want know what to do into Magento 2 ?

Comment: you can  get this type of action name in homepage

Comment: I have a multiple page how i get dynamically? what means by this

Comment: No i want dynamically all in M1 i used this Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier()

Comment: @AmitBera in M1 i used this Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier( it will get all so that i want know how to achive this in M2

Comment: her is your answer which might help you :
[Click here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142174/magento-custom-module-phtml-file-call-selected-page-only-in-system-configuration/142748#142748)

Comment: here is the answer which might help you [click here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142174/magento-custom-module-phtml-file-call-selected-page-only-in-system-configuration/142748#142748)

Answer (score 0):

Full action name for CMS home is `cms_page_view`.

In order to get  **CMS page identifier** , you need to inject

- **Cms model** **`Magento\Cms\Model\Page`**
- **`Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`**

to `__construct()` then using those you get current page **identifier**

You want to identifier  of cms page then you can get by below code:

```
/**
* Store manager
*
* @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
*/
protected $_storeManager;
/**
* @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Page
*/
protected $_page;
 public function __construct(
...
\Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page,
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
.....
    ) {
    ...
    $this->_page = $page;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    ..

    }

public function getPageDetails(){
 $pageId = $request->getParam('page_id', $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false));
 $this->_page->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
   if ($this->_page->load($pageId)) {
    echo $this->_page->getIdentifier();
    }
}
```

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: if($request->getFullActionName() == $this->getPageDetails()){
  $t1 = $request->getFullActionName();
} i get in this way it's correct

Comment: what? totally wrong code.. page identifier and full action name is  different thing.

Comment: getFullActionName is content 3 sagement of page   router name_Controllername_ActionName.

Comment: Hey my problem is in system configuration i get all cms page if i select home page i need to display on value so that how to i add condition

Comment: what is  yours exact your requirement

Comment: In my system configuration i get all cms page if i select home page i need to display one message only in home page based on selection i need to print that message

Comment: This is my problem http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142174/magento-custom-module-phtml-file-call-selected-page-only-in-system-configuration

Answer (score 0):

you can set condition in your block,
Here my block php file contains :

```
protected $_request;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_request = $request;
    ...
}


public function isHomepage()
{

    if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.x you can get the page identifier by using `getFullActionName()` method.

But in Magento 2 if you want to fetch the Page Identifiers in the same way, you have to use multiple methods.

I generally use below method to get the Page identifiers as in format `'cms_index_index'`.

```
<?php
$moduleName = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
$controllerName = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$actionName = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();

# To get the Page Identifier as 'cms_index_index' format.
$pageIdentifier = $moduleName.'_'.$controllerName .'_'.$actionName;
echo $pageIdentifier;
?>
```

This will get all the pages Identifier in `'cms_index_index'` format including your CMS and custom pages.